# Magento 2 dashboard diagram Revenue,tax,shipping 0

Tags: magento2, dashboard, statistics

there are 66 order completed in order list,but  Revenue,tax,shipping are zero
i clicked reload data and refresehd statics but still not wokring.
Pls help me

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the chart at Dashboard?

> Go to Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Dashboard > Change
>   Enable Charts to Yes.

Clear the cache and check.

Comment: yes, its enabled

Comment: Order(s) need to be at least in the processing state. Please make sure you have order(s) in processing state.

Comment: i have today more than 40 order...

Comment: i have proccesing state order.

Comment: is it depends cache?